# How to be sure the bistable circuit is set completely

Tags: digital-logic, signal

Sometimes when input signal is close to 1.4v this circuit is not set completely and the output can   stay in the middle of Vcc. How to ensure the voltage at Q1 collector will be 5V, or stay 0v in case of the low level input signal, but no way in the middle?

I am thining about using avalanche effect, when it happened the energy forced to Q3 base will be high enough to switch the output completely. Maybe trigger monostable with timing about 10us should be enough to set the ouput of bistable correctly.

[image]

**Edit:**

It is similar to this state, it is unusual but from time to time it can happened:

[image]

Is there some circuit which has sharper peak point?

Comment: Are you sure that the simulator isn't too perfect. A real circuit won't be perfectly balanced and any noise may push it one way or the other. Can you mix in a little sine or noise signal on the input?

Comment: @Transistor  I notice the simulator has problem to find stabile state in case of equality of both legs. I am curious if this situation can happened in real system.

Comment: Try injecting a 50 mV sine through 100k at the junction of R6 and D1.

Comment: As your picture depicts, such a state is not stable. I have never heard of it being encountered in practice. Noise will quickly cause the circuit to move into a stable state.

Comment: Typical case of metastability. AC coupling the input to have sharp edges sometimes helps. Also as already commented BJTs are not usually matched so one of the two wins.